# Android App JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing, url, textview

I am trying to parse JSON that I am receiving from a URL linked in my android application. I want to output this data to TextViews in my application. Source code below.

Right now this is how the JSON is displayed on the app

```
[
  {
    "IndividualID": 1,
    "FullName": "Sean Kelly",
    "DOB": "07/06/1987",
    "MedicalHistory": "Ulcerative Colitis",
    "Medication": "Asacolon",
    "Alergies": "Penicillin"
  }
]
```

Fragment2.java (commented out part is where I tried parsing but nothing is displayed)

```
package ie.itsligo.medication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    TextView txtId;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container, false);

        new LongRunningGetIO().execute();

        return view;
    }

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

        protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
           InputStream in = entity.getContent();
             StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
             int n = 1;
             while (n>0) {
                 byte[] b = new byte[4096];
                 n =  in.read(b);
                 if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
             }
             return out.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
             HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
             HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://api.myjson.com/bins/363s3");
             String text = null;
             try {
                   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 return e.getLocalizedMessage();
             }
             return text;
        }   

        protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
            if (results!=null) {

                txtId = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtId);
                txtId.setText(results);

                /*JSONObject jObj;
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray(results);
                    for (int i=0; i < jArr.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String fullname = obj.getString("FullName");
                        txtId = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtId);
                        txtId.setText(fullname+"");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your JSON has JSON Array ( [ ) as root?

Comment: @John, this is also a type of Json.

Comment: As I can see in your JSON data first element is a JSONArray but in your commented code you are using JSONObject. Moreover there is no element as 'results' in your JSON data as you are trying to parse it in your commented code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JSONArray and JSONObject classes available in the Android SDK. After you load your JSON string,you can parse it as:

```
    JSONArray myJSONArray=new JSONArray(jsonString); 
//jsonString contains your JSON loaded 
//from the Internet probably.

    for(int i=0;i<myJSONArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject obj=(JSONObject) myJSONArray.get(i);
        //Now you can access your data here.
          String individualID=obj.getString("IndividualID");//get value by key
          String fullName=obj.getString("FullName");
          //.... similarly get other values and assign them to your views accordingly.
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON library for JSON parsing in Android. You can parse this JSON in this way:

```
List<YourObject> listOfYourObject = new Gson().fromJson(results, new TypeToken<List<YourObject>>() {}.getType());
```

In the YourObject define the fields exactly how they are on the response or you can use @SerializedName annotation and name your fields how you want.